How can I sort a 2D Array so that I can arrange several Vector2Ds based on their x and y values?
I’m currently trying to practice my programming skills and am trying to create a boid simulation to cut my teeth a bit. I'm using the Godot game engine to do so, although that's not too relevant to the question.
Long story short, after achieving OK results with each boid detecting nearby boids via the Godot Physics Engine (somewhat stable with up to 350~ boids), I’m wanting to try a different approach for increased performance & amount.
I’m trying to implement a method where every boid’s position vector is stored in a two-dimensional array, as to create a ‘grid’ of Vector2s. Here’s an example of the unsorted grid with the positions (x position, y position) of 16 boids (4 rows x 4 columns):
UNSORTED:
[(1199, 864), (1259, 73), (1773, 77), (791, 504)]
[(1259, 73), (1773, 77), (791, 504), (589, 236)]
[(1773, 77), (791, 504), (589, 236), (1144, 1016)]
[(791, 504), (589, 236), (1144, 1016), (1869, 412)]

For how I want my boids to see each other without looping through every single other boid, I need to perform a sorting algorithm on this array so that positions that are closest to (0, 0) are furthest top-left, positions that are further to the right (i.e have a larger x) are placed further in the row, and positions that are further down (i. e have a larger y) are placed lower in the column.
For example, in a 4x4 grid, the boid in the most left and uppermost position
would be at grid[0][0], and the boid in the most right and lowest position would be at grid[3][3]
As to how to create the custom sorting algorithm, I’m a bit lost. Any recommendations and help would be greatly appreciated; as I’m trying to make a simulation with as many boids as possible, an algorithm with the lowest complexity possible is necessary.
Here are two of the research papers I’ve been referencing if anyone would like further context:
https://sbgames.org/sbgames2012/proceedings/papers/computacao/comp-full_11.pdf
https://vanhunteradams.com/Pico/Animal_Movement/Boids-algorithm.html
So far I've only tested one algorithm that flattened the grid array and sorted them based on the position vector magnitude. Unfortunately, this is only effective on finding the boid closest to (0,0) and the boid closest to (grid_width,grid_height), and does not properly place the other boids.
Please let me know if you need any clarifications or more info!

How fast does it need to be? You could try to store all Vectors in one list first use the built-in customn_sort of Godots array and put it in the grid after they are sorted. I tried to sort 1 000 000 Vectors and it needed like 50s..

You can't quite guarantee that the 16 boids will be evently spaced, so it's difficult to fi the grid exactly; especially as they flock, they will bunch up. What you could do is use the grid to define regions of the screen, and place multiple boids into each grid place (or none, if that region is empty). So you would have a grid of Container not just a grid of Vector2D. Then at least you would only have to look at the boids in the current and neighbouring grid cells.
If you extend this idea further, you can subdivide each grid cell similarly and you end up with a QuadTree structure.
